# ASP MVC bind data from another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I'm in trouble to solve a simple request in a view, binding from another controller.

See next screenshots :

The starting page
[image]

So the `CheckBoxList` page where I want to select some Components to add and associate to the Product (the product is assembled from several components)
[image]

As seen in this second screenshot, I get the ID of the Product (there it is "1016").

After the association, the Product page will be updated with the list of components.

I tried to add `@using PRODCHARv5.Models` in my Component View page and request in Product Controller (/Details) but with no success. So I've deleted it from my code.

How to do it ?

PRODUCT Model

```
public partial class PRODUCT
{
    public PRODUCT()
    {
        this.COMPONENT = new HashSet<COMPONENT>();
    }

    public int IDPRODUCT { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required"), StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3), Display(Name = "Product Line")]
    public string PRODUCTLINE { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required"), StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3), Display(Name = "Product Family")]
    public string PRODUCTFAMILY { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required"), StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3), Display(Name = "Product Description")]
    public string PRODUCTDESCRIPTION { get; set; }

    public string PRODUCTVERSION { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<COMPONENT> COMPONENT { get; set; }
}
```

COMPONENT Model

```
public partial class COMPONENT
{
    public COMPONENT()
    {
        this.PRODUCT = new HashSet<PRODUCT>();
        this.COMPOCHARACDAT = new HashSet<COMPOCHARACDAT>();
    }

    public int IDCOMPONENT { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required"), StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3), Display(Name = "Component Name")]
    public string COMPONENTNAME { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required"), StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3), Display(Name = "Component Class Code")]
    public string COMPONENTCLASSCODE { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required"), StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3), Display(Name = "Component Function")]
    public string COMPONENTFUNCTION { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Aera Numbering Range")]
    public string COMPONENTAERANUMBERINGRANGE { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PRODUCT> PRODUCT { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<COMPOCHARACDAT> COMPOCHARACDAT { get; set; }
}

public class ComponentModel
{
    public List<COMPONENT> Components { get; set; }
}
```

PRODUCT Controller

```
// GET: PRODUCTs/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    PRODUCT pRODUCT = db.PRODUCT.Find(id);
    if (pRODUCT == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(pRODUCT);
}
```

COMPONENT Controller

```
// GET: COMPONENTs/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    COMPONENT cOMPONENT = db.COMPONENT.Find(id);
    if (cOMPONENT == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(cOMPONENT);
}



@using PRODCHARv5.Models
@model PRODCHARv5.Models.ComponentModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BoxList";
}

<a name="top"></a>
<h2>COMPONENT BoxList</h2>
<br />

@{
    var id = Request.Url.Segments.Last();
    <label> L'ID du produit est : @id</label>
}

<br />

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
            @*<th></th>*@
            <th></th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Component Code
            </th>
            <th>
                Function
            </th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Components.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i % 4 == 0)
            {
                @:
                <tr></tr>
            }
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Components[i].IsChecked)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Components[i].IDCOMPONENT)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Components[i].COMPONENTNAME)
                </td>
                @*<td></td>*@
                <td>
                    <label>@Model.Components[i].COMPONENTNAME</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>@Model.Components[i].COMPONENTCLASSCODE</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>@Model.Components[i].COMPONENTFUNCTION</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" />
}

<br />
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button">Back to Top</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I got the issue 100% correctly from your description to be honest.

So you have a product and a list of components and you want to display a list of components the user selects and then you add them to the product.

This means you have two list of components to deal with, 1 the list of Components already associated with the product and that is coming back as part of the Product object you load via its ID. The second is the list of all available components you can choose from.

If my understanding is correct, then this is what I would do:

In the product controller, instead of returning just the product I would return a new List of component objects which contains only what the view needs to work with, this means a list of components with a boolean flag which says associated or not. You set this property to true for every component already part of the product and then in your view you can display checkboxes or whatever you want to allow selection and unselection of the components.

Add whatever other properties your view needs to these new Component objects.

Instead of thinking how you call the components controller from the products controller, the answer is simple, DON'T. This is where the Separation of Concerns principle comes into play.

Build a datalayer you can inject into whatever controller you need and use it wherever you need. This simplifies everything basically. You might want to create a new way of loading components data, you don't want to keep calling the datalayer for each component, do a bulk call by passing a list of all the IDs you want and then you get everything you need in one call to the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

For the moment, there isn't any association between the tables PRODUCT and COMPONENT.

I just want to "call" 2 informations about the PRODUCT using his ID (PRODUCTLINE and PRODUCTFAMILY >> 1st screen) from the CheckBoxList of COMPONENT >> 2nd screen where the ID is "1016").

Am I clear now ?